# Can I easily display text on alternating lines in Android/java/

Tags: java, android, user-interface, string-formatting

I have an ambitious formatting problem which has several parts and I have only a tyro’s grasp of Android programming. I want to display text from two different  files in alternating lines:

```
This is text from the first file, which is different from the second file. The 
This is the text from the second file. Notice that it isn’t a lot like the first

differences are pretty great, but take (overall) nearly the same number of 
file, but has a similar number of characters. The contents of the second 

characters, plus or minus about 5%
file should be nearly the same in length.
```

The idea is to have this display on a phone at reasonable (and adjustable) font size, with the length of the line limited by the size of the text boxes. I think I need to figure out for each text box how many characters will fit, find a method to write that many (or fewer, splitting at space or . or ! or ?) and continuing on the next text box. As the files are pretty long, I would need a method to either scroll (seems unlikely) or whole-page refresh the displays.

My questions:

1. Does my plan of attack seem reasonable?
2. Is there a library which could make this process simpler?
3. If this attack is really silly, can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: If you're gonna use a font that isn't `Monospaced`, then it is gonna be quite inefficient. As you will not be able to know the number of characters that should be on a line, until you measure how much space the line is actually taking up. But if you have a `Monospaced` font then things would get much simpler and faster. You'll be able to know the number of characters instead of guessing the best match.

Comment: Thank you. You are certainly right that this will save me trouble.

Comment: I'm glad I was of help, would you consider it an answer for your question?

Comment: Not yet.  Waiting for other helpful coders to notice my desperate plight. : )

Comment: I hope someone gives you the answer you are looking for then :D

Comment: I did; apparently I needed to clarify my question a bit. Between the three responses, I believe I have enough to start my project. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your idea is a viable approach, let me suggest yet another option: take advantage of the fact that you can place two `TextView`s in almost the same place in Android

Each `TextView` can show lines of one of the files. Both will have a line height three times as much as the font size requires (use `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`). If you place the second `TextView` a little bit lower than the first one (use `android:marginTop`), then you will get a pattern like the following:

[image]

layout xml example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".PlusOneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="3"
        android:text="@string/textview1_text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="3"
        android:text="@string/textview2_text" />

</FrameLayout>
```

strings.xml contains

```
<string name="textview1_text">This is text from the first file, which is different from the second file. The differences are pretty great, but take (overall) nearly the same number of characters, plus or minus about 5%</string>
<string name="textview2_text">This is the text from the second file. Notice that it isn’t a lot like the first file, but has a similar number of characters. The contents of the second  file should be nearly the same in length.</string>
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it's right (as far as i can tell) and contains several useful nuggets of wisdom I did not know. The coveted checkmark may yet go here, but I am hoping for some additional insight from the wise about my approach to the problem.

Comment: This is truly a nice way to apply the idea (:

Comment: Apparently the hoped-for additional wisdom is not forthcoming. Just as well; my free time has been limited. The missing piece of this puzzle is whether or not I can put some large number of these text boxes into a scrolling [something], so that entire page-equivalent amounts of text can be displayed in some kind of scrolling arrangement. is this possible?

Comment: @Peltier Cooler - why not? For example with a RecyclerView

Comment: That is exactly the sort of wisdom I was looking for. Thank you.